# Facebook logout from safari but not in app in iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, logout, sharekit

I am using ShareKit for posting any image to Facebook.

So i am facing a problem from last few days. After authorize app from Facebook when i Logout from Safari it is not logout with in an app also. I am using Single Sign-on (SSO) functionality.

and i check the same function is working fine in Android. They also use SSO. When they logout from Facebook app so they will also logout with in an app also.

Is there any code i have to add. Pls let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the iPhone app is not talking directly to the web browser like Android is. Or the iPhone app is caching the user/password.

Comment: hi which method are you called for Logout.. ?

Comment: @Yicanis Hi Thanks for your reply. can you pls explain me How Android is directly talking to Browser why not iPhone ?

Comment: @NitinGohel I am not calling any method when i logout from Facebook in Safari so it is not logout in app also.

Comment: The application on Android might be using Android's browsers cached data while the iPhone application might be independently using its own cached data. So if you erase Android's data both the browser and application are affected, whereas for the iPhone only the browser is affected. You can test this theory by logging out of the iPhone and iPhone browser and then logging in only on the iPhone application and then check if the iPhone browser is logged in as well or not. Another possibility is the iPhone application saving the browser cached data. 

Edit : albattran answered it.

Comment: @Yicanis Thanks for your quick Reply. So there is any code so  i can logout from both sides if i am logout using Safari or in app. pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a web view on the iPhone, it does not share session cookies with the browser. Hence your WebView is isolated. This is why when you log out of Facebook in Safari, your app remains logged in.
You can have the same problem in Android depending on how you launch the browser. If simply use the regular browser intent, you are basically sharing the same cookies, and hence if you log out in one, it will log out of the other one.

Comment: i am not using Web view i am opening directly Safari to login facebook then it gives me permission to post anything from app. But i am logout from Safari, it will not logout also in app still login from app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UITableView` and also put logout `UIButton` in `UITableView` Cell.

Write this code in `UIButton` click event.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[defaults facebook removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer when you are using browser OR safari in Android OR iPhone for Login.
and post anything. Then Logout from browser OR safari it is not also logout from app where we implement Facebook for posting anything on wall. They are doing same operation in both cases.

But Still i have doubt If Facebook App is available in your Android OR iPhone Device so there is happening Different Operation :( I have to search on that also.

Thanks for all your answer and help me.

Comment: Please either accept your own answer or someone else answer to help others in the future with the same problem.

Comment: I believe albattran and the comment I posted on your question were the correct answers. In which case accepting albattran's answer would suffice.